# Java realtime JPanel, JLabel + image resizing

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

#### this is my work and problem :

I'm trying to re-size jPanel and jLable using jSlider's value. (jLable is inside of jPanel) and jLable has image.

While i'm re-sizing jlable using jSlider, i want to scale to fit that image to jLable.

#### i'm used imgscaler-4.2.jar library to resize my image fit to jLable. (http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

problem is while im re-sizing jLable and jPanel it's re-sizing and image fit not working. i want to realtime re-size my jLable and jPanel + scale image fit to jlable.

#### sometime jPanel and jLable come again to it real size. :(

Help me to fix this

Thanks in advance!

#### This is my code :

```
    private void jSlider2StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      

    jPanel2.setSize(new Dimension(jSlider2.getValue(), jSlider2.getValue()));
    jLabel3.setSize(new Dimension(jSlider2.getValue(), jSlider2.getValue()));
    jPanel2.repaint();
    jLabel2.repaint();
    BufferedImage scaledImg = Scalr.resize(img, jLabel3.getHeight());
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
    jLabel3.setIcon(imageIcon);

}
```

Comment: which Layout do you use ? how you add your components to a container?

Comment: Doesn't `Scalr` have an option to allow you to define to it to fit

Comment: i want to see my full image in jlable. scalr can do it. see imgscaler-4.2 library using my link :)

Comment: @alex2410, i'm using AbsoluteLayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Oh Friends, i found the answer!it very simple.  I'm Add single jDesktopPane!  when jlable and jpanel is on jDesktopPane, it's worked! (on jframe and jPanel cant refresh this jLable and jPanel)

### Thanks ALL! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at using a `ComponentListener`. Add the listener to the label or panel in question, and when `componentResized` is invoked, scale the content to the new size. (The final three lines of code above could form the body of the `componentResized` implementation).

Also, just a note on these:

```
jPanel2.repaint();
jLabel2.repaint();
```

The `repaint` method is only a request for Swing to repaint the component when it can. It doesn't do any "inline" repainting.